# Error while trying to install a text file of packages

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I have just activated my virtualenv in Python. I have a text file in the same path named "***packages.txt***".

Below is the path:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

But, I get the following error which is shown below.

Unable to find the reason. Please guide.

Comment: You aren't even in that folder! You're in a subdirectory!

Comment: Yaa. I moved into the correct path now. When I run it, I get the same error.

Comment: Show me the command prompt again, that can't be right. Are you sure you moved it into the right place? Here. Do a directory listing (since you're on windows: `dir`) and check if both files are listed. If they are, run the command, if not you have an issue.

Comment: posted the screenshot. Please see.

Comment: Okay, now you removed the first image (it doesn't look like it was corrected).

Comment: sorry..corrected.

Comment: Please, run `dir` then run the command. I'm very curious to see if it's even listed in that directory.

Comment: Sorry, it is packages.txt.txt. My bad. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`packages.txt` exists in `Python36-32\Scripts\ENV\Scripts`, but you weren't in that directory when you ran the `pip install` command.

Comment: thanks for the reply John. Now, i moved into that path and ran it. I get the same error again. I am running the command "pip install -r packages.txt" there.

Comment: The filename is displaying in Windows Explorer as `packages.txt`, but Windows Explorer doesn't display file extensions (for example `activate.bat` is is displayed as just `activate`).  This means the _real_ filename is `packages.txt.txt`.